# Displaying a Form inside another (unbound) Form after it has been dynamically filled

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form (named: List_Items) which has a couple of controls, one being a listbox with items, when an item is selected it is added to different listbox (on same form, for re-ordering), once all re-order items are filled there is a cmd Button that will save those items to the database's 'Order' Table, then that data will fill in a third form 'Orders_Print' (descibed below) and that third form is then saved as a PDF 'DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, frmName, acFormatPDF, fileName' (sub listed below). This is all working.

I have a second form (named: Orders) which has a couple of controls, one being a listbox with (order) dates.

I have a third form (named: Orders_Print) which has a few controls on it that are filled from a Sub in a Module.

I would like the third form 'Orders_Print' to be displayed in the second forms 'Orders' for easy reading. I'm tryin to use a subform control. I can get the subform's **form** to display the correct data, but can not get the subform **control** to display this data in its parent form. As of now, the Date listbox on the 'Orders' will pass a date to the sub in the Module, fill the third form 'Orders_Print' corretlly, open the Orders_Print form, but the subform control is not displaying any data, it will only display whatever **static** data was originally saved in the Orders_Print form.

Everything is working except that I can not display 'Order_Print' form in 'Order' form.

Tried "linking" but get an unbound form error, and don't understand enough to link manually (if possible).

Also tried to Requery a lot of things (and also in different orders).

```
Me.Requery
subOrderDetails.Requery
subOrderDetails.Form.Requery
subOrderDetails.Form.Controls("txtVender").Requery
```

From the below screen shots hopefully you can see what is going on and what I'm trying to achieve.

Here is the Sub to fill "Order_Print".

The main reason for the sub is to format the Desc in the list box, I want it to be displayed in multi-line like shown in image 2.

```vb
Public Sub saveAsPDF(frmName As String, PO As String, Optional subForm As Boolean = False)

    DoCmd.OpenForm frmName
    
    Dim frm As Form
    Set frm = Forms(frmName)
    
    frm.Visible = True

    If subForm = True Then
        ' frm.Visible = False ' testing
    End If
    
    frm.txtVender = ""
    frm.txtPO = ""
    
    Dim ii As Integer
    With frm.lstOrderItems
        For ii = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            .RemoveItem (.ListCount - 1)
        Next ii
    End With
    
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim vender As String
    Dim orderDateIs As String
    
    
    ' ItemID
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    sSQL = "SELECT Orders.*, Items.ID, Items.VenderSKU as VenderSKU,Items.VenderItemName as ItemName, Venders.ID, Venders.VenderName as VenderName"
    sSQL = sSQL & " FROM (Orders INNER JOIN Items ON Orders.ItemID = Items.ID) "
    sSQL = sSQL & " left JOIN Venders ON Orders.VenderID = Venders.ID"
    sSQL = sSQL & " WHERE Orders.PO = '" & PO & "'"
    
    Set rs = getRecord(sSQL)
    Call Forms.Orders_Print.setLstItems
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        i = i + 1
        vender = rs!VenderName
        orderDateIs = Format(rs!OrderDate, "yyyy.mm.dd-hh.mm.ssAM/PM")
        orderDateIs = Replace(orderDateIs, "AM", "")
        orderDateIs = Replace(orderDateIs, "PM", "")
        
        frm.txtVender = vender
        frm.txtOrderDate = Format(rs!OrderDate, "Short Date")
        frm.txtOrderTotalCost = rs!TotalOrderCost
        
        Dim itemLen As Integer
        Dim itemNameShort As String
        Dim itemNameShortBuild As String
        Dim itemNameShortBuildArray()
        Dim x, y, z As Integer
        Dim splitStringAt As Integer
        Dim spl As Variant
        
        x = 0
        y = 0
        z = 0
        splitStringAt = 73
        
        itemNameShort = rs!ItemName
        'itemNameShort = Replace(rs!ItemName, ",", "")
        spl = Split(itemNameShort, " ")
        If Len(itemNameShort) > splitStringAt Then
            For x = 0 To UBound(spl)
                
                itemNameShortBuild = itemNameShortBuild & spl(x) & " "
                
                If Len(itemNameShortBuild) < splitStringAt Then
                    itemNameShort = itemNameShortBuild
                Else
                    ReDim Preserve itemNameShortBuildArray(y)
                    itemNameShortBuildArray(y) = itemNameShort
                    itemNameShortBuild = ""
                    y = y + 1
                    x = x - 1
                End If
                
            Next x
            
            ReDim Preserve itemNameShortBuildArray(y)
            itemNameShortBuildArray(y) = itemNameShort
            
            itemNameShortBuild = ""
            itemNameShort = ""
            
        Else
            ReDim Preserve itemNameShortBuildArray(0)
            itemNameShortBuildArray(y) = itemNameShort
        End If
        
        itemNameShortBuild = ""
        itemNameShort = ""
        
        For z = 0 To UBound(itemNameShortBuildArray)
            If z = 0 Then
                frm.lstOrderItems.AddItem rs!VenderSKU & ";'" & itemNameShortBuildArray(z) & "';" & rs!OrderQTY & ";$" & rs!TotalItemCost
            Else
                frm.lstOrderItems.AddItem ";'" & itemNameShortBuildArray(z) & "';;"
            End If
        Next z
        
        
       frm.lstOrderItems.Selected(i) = False
       rs.MoveNext
       
       frm.txtPO = PO
    Loop
    
    If subForm = False Then
        fileName = projectPath & "POs\" & vender & "\"
        Call makeDir(fileName)
        
        fileName = fileName & "PO." & PO & "_" & vender & "_" & orderDateIs & "_" & currentUserName & ".pdf"
        
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, frmName, acFormatPDF, fileName
        DoCmd.Close acForm, frmName, acSaveNo
        Call runit(fileName)
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/SuXjTue.png]
[image: https://i.imgur.com/UMOohhh.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working...

The subform.control.form needs to be populated "through" the parent form. I was tring to populate the subform itself, then "refresh" it in the parent form.

Changed the top part of the Sub

from

```
    DoCmd.OpenForm frmName
    
    Dim frm As Form
    Set frm = Forms(frmName)
    
    frm.Visible = True

    If subForm = True Then
        ' frm.Visible = False ' testing
    End If
```

to

```
Dim frm As Form

If subForm = True Then
    Set frm = Forms("Orders").subOrderDetails.Form
Else
    DoCmd.OpenForm frmName
    Set frm = Forms(frmName)
    frm.Visible = True
End If
```